# php csv converting

Tags: php, csv

How can I convert this my csv file containing strings like this:

"Sep 03, 00:30","(Australia) TD Securities Inflation (MoM)",Medium,0.2%,,0.6%

Into this format:

2012.09.03;00:30;AUD;TD Securities inflation m/m;1;;-;0.2%

- using PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing the business rules, that's impossible to answer!

Comment: What have you done to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this strategy:

- read the line by line
- explode the line into a array
- go over each array element, adjust it to your needs
- if necessary change the order of the elements
- implode the array to a line
- write the line to a file

Comment: Or just `fgetcsv()` and `fputcsv()` to replace the first and last two points.